# How to get the sum of a list of numbers with recursion? (getting the list as an input)

Tags: python

I don't know how to write this problem in python. Specially this problem wants to get a list from input and then calculate its sum.

```
def sum(num):
    Sum = 0
    for i in num:
        Sum = Sum + i
    return Sum
```

Comment: Observe: the sum of an empty list is 0. The sum of a non-empty list is its first element + the sum of the rest of the list.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
def sum_recursive(listt):
    if len(listt) == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return listt[0] + sum_recursive(listt[1:])
```

```
print(sum_recursive([10,20,30]))
>> 60
```

```
print(sum_recursive([]))
>> 0
```